# Why jquery focus not working in IE8?

Tags: jquery

I use the below code to focus form first element by default when the page load initial.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
    $(':input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
  });
})
```

but this seems to be not working in IE8 ???

Comment: since there is `$(function() {}`, you don't need `$(window).load()`.

Comment: and... can  `$(':input:visible:enabled:first')`  select anything in another browser?

Comment: no luck, still it is not focusing

Comment: @logudotcom: have answered bitsmix second comment

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
$(function () {

    $(':input:visible:enabled:first').focus();

})
```

works for me on IE 8

http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/BxcZB/3/